# Saving callback function scope

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's imagine i have a function that takes a callback argument

```js
function saveCallback(callback) {
  //Export this callback to another file?
  //fsextra.outputFile("./file.js", callback)?
}
```

and pass it

```js
function outsideScope {
//
}

let someVarOutside = 0;

saveCallback(function() {
    outsideScope()
    someVarOutside = 2;
})
```

Would there be a way to export that callback parameter to another file? With exporting im talking about, copying it to another file, But obviously, i would not just be able to cut the function code and export it, as it may contain stuff from outside of that function scope

This may seem like im trying to solve a problem in the most inefficient way possible, but this is a special case.

Also i would probably be able to copy the ENTIRE callback file to have the correct scopes, variables etc, but that seems a bit too overkill in my opinion.

Comment: Scope only exists in the context of a running process, it can't be saved in a file.

Comment: @Barmar Yeahh... thats my little problem here

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. You need to determine specifically what you need to save, and save it explicitly, rather than trying to save the entire scope.